# ROO ITD Push In results in a "Requested Resource not found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have a scaffolded controller with a populate method. I wanted to customize this method, so I did an ITD 'push in' and re-implemented it. Everything compiled and Roo updated the aspect, but when accessing the controller with the browser, I get a "Requested resource not found".

I'm using SpringSource tc Server Developer Edition v2.0. No exceptions are logged in the console.

Environment:
Mac - Snow Leopard
Java 1.6
sts-2.3.3.M2
roo-1.1.0.M2

Comment: Could you post the controller and its ITD before and after the push-in please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by pushing in the complete aspect into the controller class. 
I had the impression that this wasn't necessary, but for now I don't really mind that.